# What will be the linq equivalent of db join with group by

Tags: c#, sql, linq

What will be linq equivalent of the following query:

```
SELECT
   h.State,COUNT(p.NPRID)
   FROM PopulationRegistrationEntity p
   INNER JOIN HouseListingEntity h
   ON h.CensusHouseNoID = p.CensusHouseNoID
   GROUP BY h.State
```

I have tried it but not working:

```
var a = (from h in db.HouseListingEntity
                     join p in db.PopulationRegistrationEntity on h.CensusHouseNoID equals p.CensusHouseNoID
                     group p by new { h.State } into g
                     select new { State = g.Key.State, Count = g.Count(p1 => p1.NPRID > 0) });
```

Comment: "not working" is a little big vague.

Answer (score 3):

Group `h` instead of `p`:

```
var a = (from h in db.HouseListingEntity
         join p in db.PopulationRegistrationEntity on h.CensusHouseNoID equals p.CensusHouseNoID
         group h by h.State into g
         select new { State = g.Key.State, Count = g.Count(p1 => p1.NPRID > 0) });
```

> Showing compile time error in the last line of code at g.Key.State and p1.NPRID

Use a `let` clause:

```
var a = (from h in db.HouseListingEntity
         join p in db.PopulationRegistrationEntity on h.CensusHouseNoID equals p.CensusHouseNoID
         let temp = new { HouseListingEntity = h, PopulationRegistrationEntity = p }
         group temp by temp.HouseListingEntity.State into g
         select new { State = g.Key, Count = g.Count(p1 => p1.PopulationRegistrationEntity.NPRID > 0) });
```

Comment: Showing compile time error in the last line of code at
    g.Key.State   and    p1.NPRID

Comment: @CodingbyRaj: Try to use a `let` clause. See my edit.